# Can' fix fxml.LoadException

Tags: java, javafx

I know that many people ask about this problem, and Iread about this error and I tried to fix that, but I don't know why it's still does not work.

I got this code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And I tried to change getResource part like this "/Login.fxml". But it still does not work.

This is how project files look:
[image]

Comment: Check the FXML files are being deployed to the build folder (should be being copied by your IDE to the same folder that has `Main.class`). Also post the stack trace.

Comment: Or at least the error message. (Stacktrace would be way batter.) There are multiple errors that could be thrown when loading the fxml. The *"Location not set"* error you're probably refering to is just one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login.fxml"));
```

to

```
Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application/Login.fxml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since FXML is in the same path you can do something like this:

```
 Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("Login.fxml"));
```

You should verify Login.fxml is defined as a resource in the project and it's present in the output directory .